How to pipe GPG decryption into GPG encryption?
I would like to decrypt a file and edit it without writing its clear content to a temporary file, to avoid leaks of sensitive data.
I've already created the original file with this command:
echo -n "hello world" | gpg --encrypt --symmetric --output sensitive.gpg

I can decrypt this file and output it:
$ gpg --decrypt sensitive.gpg
gpg: AES256.OCB encrypted session key
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: encrypted with cv25519 key, ID <blablabla>
hello world

However, when I try to pipe the output to gpg --encrypt, it seems like the two processes are running simultaneously and try to consume stdin at the same time:
gpg --no-symkey-cache --pinentry-mode loopback --decrypt sensitive.gpg | gpg --encrypt --symmetric --pinentry-mode loopback --output sensitive.gpg

Before I enter any password, here is the output:
gpg: AES256.OCB encrypted session key
Enter passphrase: Enter passphrase:

You can see it's asking me the password twice.
And here are the running processes:
$ ps | grep gpg
49716 ttys002    0:00.02 gpg --no-symkey-cache --pinentry-mode loopback --decrypt sensitive.gpg
49717 ttys002    0:00.01 gpg --encrypt --symmetric --pinentry-mode loopback --output sensitive.gpg

Is there any solution for gpg --encrypt to wait for gpg --decrypt to do its job?
I would like to add an editor like vipe in between those two commands.


would like to decrypt a file and edit it without writing its clear content to a temporary file, to avoid leaks of sensitive data.

That part of the plan isn't compatible with the plan to use vipe, which creates a temporary file. If you look at the status bar you'll see that you're editing /tmp/sZDlroW8Q3 or something similar.
But dpending on your OS, it might have a way to create in-memory temporary files. For example, Linux often makes /tmp in-memory (although still swappable to disk but that's already true of your text editor's process memory). Other systems might have a "ramdisk" feature of some kind.

it seems like the two processes are running simultaneously

They do; that's how pipes are designed to work.

and try to consume stdin at the same time:

That's not the problem, as their stdin is connected to different sources: the second process isn't reading stdin from the terminal but from the other end of the corresponding | pipe.
The problem comes from the two programs manually opening the terminal device (/dev/tty) – which is indeed done so that they could read the password without disturbing their stdin.

Is there any solution for gpg --encrypt to wait for gpg --decrypt to do its job?

Processes in a pipeline are always started concurrently. The solution therefore depends on whether the 2nd passphrase prompt is shown as soon as gpg starts, or only as soon as it receives data – for decryption it might be the latter, but for encryption it's most likely the former.
So you need to replace the second gpg with a wrapper that first buffers its stdin to a temporary file and only then runs the actual gpg. (Actually the script is similar for both cases.)
With delayed start (letting the script start the command):
#!/bin/sh
# gpg --decrypt | vipe | buffer gpg --encrypt
tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/bipe_XXXXXXXX)
cat > "$tmp"
cat "$tmp" | "$@"
rm -f "$tmp"

Without (likely to be completely redundant once you add vipe):
#!/bin/sh
# gpg --decrypt | vipe | buffer | gpg --encrypt
tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/bipe_XXXXXXXX)
cat > "$tmp"
cat "$tmp"
rm -f "$tmp"

Again, the vipe editor already works in exactly this way – it saves its input to a temporary file before invoking a regular Vim instance – so you're not really losing any security by doing so. In fact, you could just as well integrate that into the script.
With delayed start:
#!/bin/sh
# gpg --decrypt | bipe gpg --encrypt
tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/bipe_XXXXXXXX)
cat > "$tmp"
${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}} "$tmp"
cat "$tmp" | "$@"
rm -f "$tmp"

Without delayed start: would be identical to vipe itself.
